# Failing creation of bean in spring

Tags: spring, weblogic, spring-webflow, spring-ioc

this is the log

and this are the entries in my xml file..

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
  </bean>


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter.<init>(Lorg/springframework/oxm/Marshaller;Lorg/springframework/oxm/Unmarshaller;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for resolved class, org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/oxm/Marshaller used in the signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter.<init>(Lorg/springframework/oxm/Marshaller;Lorg/springframework/oxm/Unmarshaller;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for resolved class, org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/oxm/Marshaller used in the signature
```

help me to resolve the issue
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it looks like a 'transitive dependency' problem. To put that in plain English lets call a library a dependency. A transitive dependency would be a library that the library is using to do its job.

Problems can occur when two libraries are expecting a different version of some common library.

Also, it could be the application server that is providing this library and making it visible to the main class loader. In this case you may be able to find the offending jar, take it out and just use the app server version. Try taking out the spring-oxm jar and seeing if the required classes are provided by the server.

It can help to have a library manager to set up all the jars for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info i am able to resolved my issue :) by putting my jar in servers lib folder

Comment: Careful with that approach, @Vinod. Especially if you overwrote a jar that was already there, you probably affected something you didn't intend to in the server itself. Even if not, you just made a jar globally available to all apps, and probably higher in priority than any deployed with individual apps (not knowing WebLogic myself, I can't say for sure).